# How to get only current selection opation from asp.net listbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hello I want to arrange columns as per your select. my listbox showing checkboxes in alphabitcal order but i what i want when user select any column i want to prepare a jquery string variable and want to store the value of current select option from listbox not in order how the listbox showing the data.

my jquery is something like

`$("#<%=lstQuery.ClientID %>").change(function(e) { console.log($(this).children('option:selected').val()); });`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#your_select').change(function() {
  console.log('You selected: ', this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="your_select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).